# change color and thickness of wireframe node

Tags: wireframe, toon-shading

I want to make a non flickering wireframe render. Like when we turn the object.
In this video, is my object using the freestyle grease pencil and is flickering a lot in the upper part. I tried erasing some of the overlapping edges, but there are many.
https://youtube.com/shorts/3nNunLokg5k

Then I tried with the wireframe modifier, but the back faces of course are shown and well,is not what i wanted.

Until I read about the wireframe node in the shading section! But now i have 2 questions: how can I increase the contour lines thickness as well as changing the color?
I have no idea on how to search for it. Could it be maybe another node in rendering? Or could it be inside the shading?

[image: how to change the color of the wireframe node]

thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image]I managed to do it by connecting the emission shader to the other shader input in the mix shader.
Still unsure on how to make the outline thicker, but like this works!